# Lock file Deployment issue in Digitalocean for a react project

Tags: reactjs, npm, digital-ocean

I am facing a deployment error in digitalocean when building a react app. This is the error I am getting:

```
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! code EUSAGE
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! 
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! 
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's ajv@6.12.6 does not satisfy ajv@8.11.0
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 does not satisfy json-schema-traverse@1.0.0
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! Missing: typescript@4.8.3 from lock file
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! Missing: ajv-keywords@3.5.2 from lock file
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! Missing: ajv-keywords@3.5.2 from lock file
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! Missing: ajv-keywords@3.5.2 from lock file
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! 
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! Clean install a project
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! 
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! Usage:
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! npm ci
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! 
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! Options:
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! [--no-audit] [--foreground-scripts] [--ignore-scripts]
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! [--script-shell <script-shell>]
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! 
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! 
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] 
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] npm ERR!     /home/apps/.npm/_logs/2022-09-10T06_12_09_240Z-debug-0.log
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] 
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] unable to invoke layer creator
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] installing node_modules: exit status 1
    [2022-09-10 06:12:10] ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
    [2022-09-10 06:12:12] 
    [2022-09-10 06:12:12] For documentation on the buildpacks used to build your app, please see:
    [2022-09-10 06:12:12] 
    [2022-09-10 06:12:12]    Node.js  v0.3.4  https://do.co/apps-buildpack-node
    [2022-09-10 06:12:12] 
    [2022-09-10 06:12:12]  ! Build failed
```

I generated the local file again by running the npm install command bu I am getting this error, what should I be doing?